# Select nth row after orderby in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to select the second row for each group of names. I used orderby to sort by name and then the purchase date/timestamp. It is important that I select the second purchase for each name (by datetime).

Here is the data to build dataframe:

```
data = [
  ('George', datetime(2020, 3, 24, 3, 19, 58), datetime(2018, 2, 24, 3, 22, 55)),
  ('Andrew', datetime(2019, 12, 12, 17, 21, 30), datetime(2019, 7, 21, 2, 14, 22)),
  ('Micheal', datetime(2018, 11, 22, 13, 29, 40), datetime(2018, 5, 17, 8, 10, 19)),
  ('Maggie', datetime(2019, 2, 8, 3, 31, 23), datetime(2019, 5, 19, 6, 11, 33)),
  ('Ravi', datetime(2019, 1, 1, 4, 19, 47), datetime(2019, 1, 1, 4, 22, 55)),
  ('Xien', datetime(2020, 3, 2, 4, 33, 51), datetime(2020, 5, 21, 7, 11, 50)),
  ('George', datetime(2020, 3, 24, 3, 19, 58), datetime(2020, 3, 24, 3, 22, 45)),
  ('Andrew', datetime(2019, 12, 12, 17, 21, 30), datetime(2019, 9, 19, 1, 14, 11)),
  ('Micheal', datetime(2018, 11, 22, 13, 29, 40), datetime(2018, 8, 19, 7, 11, 37)),
  ('Maggie', datetime(2019, 2, 8, 3, 31, 23), datetime(2018, 2, 19, 6, 11, 42)),
  ('Ravi', datetime(2019, 1, 1, 4, 19, 47), datetime(2019, 1, 1, 4, 22, 17)),
  ('Xien', datetime(2020, 3, 2, 4, 33, 51), datetime(2020, 6, 21, 7, 11, 11)),
  ('George', datetime(2020, 3, 24, 3, 19, 58), datetime(2020, 4, 24, 3, 22, 54)),
  ('Andrew', datetime(2019, 12, 12, 17, 21, 30), datetime(2019, 8, 30, 3, 12, 41)),
  ('Micheal', datetime(2018, 11, 22, 13, 29, 40), datetime(2017, 5, 17, 8, 10, 38)),
  ('Maggie', datetime(2019, 2, 8, 3, 31, 23), datetime(2020, 3, 19, 6, 11, 12)),
  ('Ravi', datetime(2019, 1, 1, 4, 19, 47), datetime(2018, 2, 1, 4, 22, 24)),
  ('Xien', datetime(2020, 3, 2, 4, 33, 51), datetime(2018, 9, 21, 7, 11, 41)),
]
 
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['name', 'trial_start', 'purchase'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

I order the data by name and then purchase

```
df.orderBy("name","purchase").show()
```

to produce the result:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   name|        trial_start|           purchase|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Andrew|2019-12-12 22:21:30|2019-07-21 06:14:22|
| Andrew|2019-12-12 22:21:30|2019-08-30 07:12:41|
| Andrew|2019-12-12 22:21:30|2019-09-19 05:14:11|
| George|2020-03-24 07:19:58|2018-02-24 08:22:55|
| George|2020-03-24 07:19:58|2020-03-24 07:22:45|
| George|2020-03-24 07:19:58|2020-04-24 07:22:54|
| Maggie|2019-02-08 08:31:23|2018-02-19 11:11:42|
| Maggie|2019-02-08 08:31:23|2019-05-19 10:11:33|
| Maggie|2019-02-08 08:31:23|2020-03-19 10:11:12|
|Micheal|2018-11-22 18:29:40|2017-05-17 12:10:38|
|Micheal|2018-11-22 18:29:40|2018-05-17 12:10:19|
|Micheal|2018-11-22 18:29:40|2018-08-19 11:11:37|
|   Ravi|2019-01-01 09:19:47|2018-02-01 09:22:24|
|   Ravi|2019-01-01 09:19:47|2019-01-01 09:22:17|
|   Ravi|2019-01-01 09:19:47|2019-01-01 09:22:55|
|   Xien|2020-03-02 09:33:51|2018-09-21 11:11:41|
|   Xien|2020-03-02 09:33:51|2020-05-21 11:11:50|
|   Xien|2020-03-02 09:33:51|2020-06-21 11:11:11|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

How might I get the second row for each name? In pandas it was easy. I could just use nth. I have been looking at sql but have not found a solution. Any suggestions appreciated.

The output I am looking for would be:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   name|        trial_start|           purchase|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Andrew|2019-12-12 22:21:30|2019-08-30 07:12:41|
| George|2020-03-24 07:19:58|2020-03-24 07:22:45|
| Maggie|2019-02-08 08:31:23|2019-05-19 10:11:33|
|Micheal|2018-11-22 18:29:40|2018-05-17 12:10:19|
|   Ravi|2019-01-01 09:19:47|2019-01-01 09:22:17|
|   Xien|2020-03-02 09:33:51|2020-05-21 11:11:50|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `window row_number()` function then filter only the **`2`** row after ordering by **`purchase`**.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w=Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(col("purchase"))

df.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") ==2).drop(*["rn"]).show()
```

**`SQL Api:`**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true")

sql("select `(rn)?+.+` from (select *,row_number() over(partition by name order by purchase) rn from tmp) e where rn =2").\
show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I got your sql working. I also did it another way: ```sqlContext.sql("select name, trial_start, purchase \
from \
( \
select name, trial_start, purchase, \
row_number() over(partition by name order by purchase asc) as rn \
from table \
) x \
where x.rn = 2;").show()```

Comment: I'd like to get your Window approach to work. I get an error on col which I have not figured out. Any thoughts?

```from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w=Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(col("purchase"))
df.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") ==2).drop(["rn"]).show()
```

Comment: ```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in   3   4 w=Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(col("purchase"))
----> 5 df.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") ==2).drop(["rn"]).show()
~/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in drop(self, *cols)
   2141              jdf = self._jdf.drop(col._jc)
   2142             else:
-> 2143                 raise TypeError("col should be a string or a Column")
   2144         else:
   2145             for col in cols:
TypeError: col should be a string or a Column
```

Comment: Would be nice if I could add one reply with all the info needed but fields are too small. Not sure the right way to respond with that much detail

Comment: Try with **`.drop(*["rn"])`** we need to unnest the list in `drop` with `*`, I wrongly copied to answer..!

Comment: Where I might I get more info on regular expressions such (rn)?+.+` ? I can't quite google that particular one. I want to better understand what that is doing. Thx in advance.

Comment: You can test all regex in this site https://regex101.com  this will be good start https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: What does  drop(*["rn"])  do?